# Title within url variable

Tags: php

`$element` contains an image, like: `<img src='example.com/img.png'>`. Is there anyway I can add the title `$descr` on `$element` instead of the current anchor wrapping it?

```
echo "<a class='target-link' target='_blank' title='$descr' href='$url'>$element</a>";
```

Comment: what do you mean "add the title $descr on $element" ?

Comment: did you tried to add variable $descr within your <img tag as alt??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this I hope this is the same you are looking for

```
$desrc   = "This is normal text";
$element = "<img src='https://www.example.com' alt='$desrc' />";
echo "<a href='#' title='$desrc'>".$element."</a>";
```

Or you can try by using it like this

```
$desrc   = "This is normal text";
$element = "<img src='https://www.example.com' alt='' />";
echo "<a href='#' target='_blank' title='$desrc'>".str_replace("alt='game img'", "title='".$desrc."'", $element)."</a>";
```

Comment: Not sure how I'm gonna fit that in an echo with all the "" and ''.. I've tried: `echo "<a class='target-link' target='_blank'  href='$url'>".str_replace(\"alt=\"game img\"\", \"title='$descr'\", $element)."</a>";` among others..

Comment: check the updated code and use  single quotes inside